# CSS space origin unknown

Tags: css

I am trying to solve this problem with someone and we fail to figure this out.

What happen is when the media queries kick in the `.entry` becomes `display: table;` and the `.entry-wrap` and `.entry-footer` become `display: table-cell`.

The problem is that there is a space after the table layout kicks in and I have no clue why its there and how to make it go away.

[image]

I have uploaded the design here [link removed design not intended for public yet].

Comment: looks like vertical-align:bottom | middle; applied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please add following to your appropriate media queries:

```
.entry-wrap {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: top; /* <- add this line */
}
```

and eventually you can add this too:

```
.entry-footer {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: bottom; /* <- add this line */
   width: 190px;
   background-color: #489eba;
}
```

Comment: Oh damn, table cells are middle by default. Thanks so much ;). I not thought of this.

Comment: Well damn, someone beat me to it :P. @redanimalwar The table layout seems to have been computed before the `width` is applied to `.entry-footer`, so the table height is determined by the computed height of `.entry-footer` before it gets a width that makes its height smaller. This is what leads to the auto-computed padding that `.entry` has on top, and `.entry-footer` has on bottom. The vertical alignment then makes it look strange, hence why you need to set it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You have this CSS rule on line 5548 of `style.css`:

```
.entry,
.entry-comments,
.comment-respond,
.author-box {
  background: #b7d9e4;
  border-top: 6px solid #489eba;
}
```

This is being applied to the `article#post-xxxx` elements, since the have the class `entry` on them. The space is coming from the `border-top` property.

The `border-top` is the same color as the right column with the pencil, so it looks like the space might be elsewhere other than the border, when it's not. You can clearly see how the border is applied if you change the border color.

Comment: What does this intended 6px border have to do with the ~100px space? Maybe my image and the arrows did mislead you. I want the entire space where the red arrows are disappear.

Comment: @redanimalwar Ahhh, yes, the arrows seem to point at the small darker blue bar across the very top, so I thought you meant that.